# Why are hydropower plants always wheel-shaped and not flat?

Tags: power-engineering

**Question:**
Why are there no flat power generators like in the picture below, that work on the surface of shallow, but steadily flowing rivers ?  (As a floating micropower plant.)

[image]

The picture shows a conveyer belt with vanes/blades(?) attached to it. The water flow moves the conveyer belt. A generator could be attached to the front and back "wheel" of the belt.

[Here's](http://%5B!%5Benter%20image%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5D%5D%5B1%5D) a video of something similar. I would just build it on a larger river.

**Why would I ask this?**

There are much more flat rivers than waterfall-like structures on this planet. Using them looks like a much more non-nature-inversive, cheap solution. Having a longer surface should supply better drag by flowing water.

Comment: Have you checked Francis turbines - as used for shallower rivers?

Comment: As far as I could tell, they are also round. Regarding their use, they are afaik highly optimized turbines, that can only be used with high fall and much water. Ie their usage is highly constrainted.

Comment: Pelton is high fall... any turbine to be efficient is optimised to the location. Seems like you need to check all three: Pelton, Francis and Kaplan...

Comment: I we go that route: The question is about, why not stretch the idea of a Pelton turbine? Maybe information on the internet is wrong. But all three are wheel shaped. (I tried to precise my question)

Comment: If you look at your design, there will be lower friction losses if you compress the length of your device so it has one axle instead of two... Do make the effort to check out the water wheels that have been in use for centuries under, over and breast shot come to mind.

Comment: The main reason is construction cost of the chute and the fact that a shallow chute losses more energy to friction than a pipe of free jet. And you can't do run of the river because of the trash, trees, and fishing line, although a self powered trash skimmer wouldn't be bad, they have been built for skimming the ocean and some river mouths.

Comment: Please note the amount of site civil engineering that goes in to these things, as illustrated here - https://mavel.cz/turbines/kaplan/#:~:text=Mavel's%20Kaplan%20turbines%20are%20optimal,be%20single%20or%20double%20regulated.

Comment: Also, the cost of any low quality power source (low head hydro in this case) is going to go about as the inverse of the square of the head (or inversely proportional to velocity), so at some point, nothing makes sense, and at the point where things start to make sense, a paddle wheel doesn't cut it. But [Gorlov Rotors](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/666280) are marginally competitive in some applications, including partially submerged ROTR applications.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your diagram.  The vanes rotate, so multiple circular motions.   The reason rivers are not harnessed is because the magnitude of voltage generated depends upon water velocity.  There is not enough energy to be cost effective.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: The blades/vanes don't rotate. This is basically the limousine version of water wheel

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't get your point. You want to express that many smart people think very hard and therefore all non-used technology is probably not efficient enough?

Comment: So irregardless of rotation, do you know of any working water mills?   Work out energy with actual flow rates of a river.   When you have no electrical grid, harnessing river flow  makes sense, but not today.  If a water wheel is not cost effective, how is your concept going to improve on that?  Your idea may be great, but I don't see how it even harnesses energy.  Flow and head allow cost effective energy harvesting.  You have neither!

Comment: Just got it.  It is a conveyor belt.  Maybe vanes on ends would of helped or upper and lower vanes not aligning.  So where is your generator?   The axels.  That is rotation or wheel shaped.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I added a description to the image. I could imagine two generators. One for each "wheel".

Comment: This is simple physics.  Even if your conveyor is super efficient, there is not enough energy in flowing river water to make it meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to solve a problem, the best start is to look at previous attempts. To provide some perspective, I'm doing that for you now. You are not looking at a typical hydro power plant where a dam provides a high head, and the flow is ducted onto a a francis or pelton turbine. You are describing a microhydropower installation with a floating turbine.

Floating hydrpower allows capturing some power without building a dam. The turbine could be placed in or near the middle of the river, where the current is fastest. An installation with a damn will always harvest  vastly more power from the same river.

Before electrical power transmission became widespread, there used to be boat mills - workshops with machinery driven by water wheels, placed on boats.

[image]

(Boat mill in Servia, 1900, Image from [lowtechmagazine page on boat mills](https://www.lowtechmagazine.com/2010/11/boat-mills-bridge-mills-and-hanging-mills.html))

Improvised versions have also been used for electricity generation.

Floating hydro power is, AFAICT, an ongoing area of developement. The two most common turbine shapes appear to be a propeller hanging from buoys:

[image]

([Image source](https://siamagazin.com/smart-hydro-powers-floating-river-canal-turbines-to-provide-electricity-to-remote-locations/))

... Or some sort of flat paddle wheel:

[image]

Vertical axis turbines also exist.

I think [Kamran](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/39766/61) explains quite well why a propeller or a paddle wheel is used, rather than a conveyor belt. I will just add this: Look at the water wheel in the direction of flow: You want to maximise area here.

Answer (score 2):

The incoming stream of water flow momentum is transferred to the radial blade of the turbine wheel when it hits the slow blade of the turbine, giving it its kinetic energy, and pushing it out of the way making room for the tail stream to keep rushing in, continuing the momentum and the process.

$$W=\dot{m}v^2_{initial}-\dot{m}v^2_{final}$$

In linear track in your figure, the flow gets trapped in the buckets moving along with them. There is very little exchange of energy because the speed of the stream is more or less the same as the track, only the front wheel is working.

And the flow of the tail end of the stream gets slowed down and goes around the track.

Comment: This is what you're trying to say?: In a round turbine (e.g. Kaplan) energy gets **added** through the blade. This allows the turbine to turn faster, than the river flows. However in my linear approach, energy is not added but **set** to the speed of the river. || But  don't old water wheels have the same problem?

Comment: the trick is to catch the maximum possible energy od the stream. if your turbine sqeezez all the energy out of the stream it means the discharge kinetic energy is zero, meaning no mass coming out, not possible. if the difference in the speed of blade and the stream is too small, not an efficient turbine. if you google Carno principle you find what he proved about max energy available from a flow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. For me your and mart's answer together helped. I would've like to accepted both answers. As I needed mart's answer to get a better grasp of yours, I decided to take is as accepted.